# getting URL of pages with ajax

Tags: html, ajax

This is a webpage with a number of "subpages" embedded in ajax for all the user reviews. 
http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13636400-the-bone-season#

I am trying to get the specific URL for particular pages (say ?page=4), so I can point people to particular reviews directly instead of going to the page and clicking on page4. below is a snippet from the source code for that page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Ajax.Request('/book/reviews/13636400-the-bone-season?page=4', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get', parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('XsOgyhAC4p0tAm8wGIqTQGY+PxGpDieI45AYry0NlE4=')}); return false;">
```

when i type http://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/13636400-the-bone-season?page=4, i get a blank page.

What do I need to do get the page to show? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

New answer: you need to submit a GET request (using cURL for example) with the parameter mentioned (`'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('XsOgyhAC4p0tAm8wGIqTQGY+PxGpDieI45AYry0NlE4='`), and parse what is sent back. Then you'll get your review. Linking to it is not possible unless you find a URL where your review is always displayed.

Comment: i tried the following URL (with the authenticity encoding), but i am getting a 406 error

http://www.goodreads.com/book/reviews/13636400-the-bone-season?page=4&authenticity_token=XsOgyhAC4p0tAm8wGIqTQGY%2BPxGpDieI45AYry0NlE4%3D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url for the specific reviews, but I was unable to find anyway to do so for the "page".  If you want to direct someone to a specific review, then you can get that url from the "see review" link or the date link on that particular review.